# Apache not responding in amazon ec2

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, amazon-ec2

Well this might sound awkward but I facing terrible issue with my Amazon EC2 instance

one of the finding I see is that apache is not responding on port 80 which is weird because I can't even find the incoming packet to port 80 in tcpdump output

As per the security rules all security rules are in place correctly at least in amazon console

I restarted the apache to listen to port 8080 and added port 8080 and add 8080 to security rule and everything work but I cant just able to understand as to why the port 80 not responding

Needless to say since port 8080 is responding all my CNAME and A-record is working too

## UPDATE

No firewall issue either I just cross check the iptables and list is empty

### Updated with security policies

```
22 (SSH)     0.0.0.0/0  Delete
80 (HTTP)    0.0.0.0/0  Delete
443 (HTTPS)  0.0.0.0/0  Delete
5678         0.0.0.0/0  Delete
8080 (HTTP*) 0.0.0.0/0  Delete
```

FYI Ubuntu 12.04 server 64 bits

Can some share a light on this

Comment: Have you checked that there is nothing else listening on port 80? run netstat -tulpn | grep 80 and see if anything is listed.

Comment: i did lsof -i ':80' and all output respond to apache 2

Comment: What does your security policy look like?

Comment: You need to update your question with your AWS security group configuration so that we can see if something's wrong in there.

Comment: @talonx update the question with security policies

Comment: @NathanC Update the security policy

Comment: From inside the EC2 instance, does 'telnet localhost 80' work (assuming you're back to running Apache on 80) ?

Comment: just tried now when I telnet from outside the server it does not connect when I'm telnetting to port 80 from ec2 instance i see `occasionally` log getting written to apache2 access log not sure why ? such is the case

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get a VPC security group, and a non-vpc security group confused when you entered in port 80?  Try turning off the firewall on your server and see if it responds...